# How do I drop a MongoDB database using PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to drop a database in MongoDB similarly to

```
use <DBNAME>
db.dropDatabase()
```

in the Mongo shell.

How do I do that in PyMongo?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**PyMongo 2.4 up to at least 3.11.4**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('<HOST>', <PORT>)
client.drop_database('<DBNAME>')
```

- [PyMongo Stable documentation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.drop_database)
- [PyMongo 3.2.1 documentation](https://api.mongodb.org/python/3.2.1/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html?highlight=drop_database#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.drop_database)

**PyMongo 2.3 and earlier**

```
from pymongo import Connection
connection = Connection('<HOST>', <PORT>)
connection.drop_database('<DBNAME>')
```

- [PyMongo 2.3 documentation](https://api.mongodb.org/python/2.3/api/pymongo/connection.html#pymongo.connection.Connection.drop_database)
- [PyMongo 1.0 documentation](https://api.mongodb.org/python/1.0/pymongo.connection.Connection-class.html#drop_database)

Answer (score 7):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('<HOST>', <PORT>)
client.db.command("dropDatabase")
```

see copydb example: https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/copydb.html

You can also use runCommand helper to run other commands, detail see https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/command/